# Is it possible for my bluetooth headset to have high microphone input?

Tags: macos, windows-8, bluetooth, microphone, headset

I feel like I'm approaching this problem from the opposite direction from many on the interwebs. I don't care very much about speaker quality. I spend most of the day in voip calls in Google Hangouts and Skype. All of my team mates use wired headsets and their microphone audio quality is superb. I am trying out a bluetooth headset for the 10th time in 5 years (because I keep hoping it will get better), and the microphone quality sucks SO bad that I'm probably going to end up taking this headset back (again).

I care about how I sound to other people. [Here's](http://mikelward.com/625usb.wma) how I want to sound. [Here](http://mikelward.com/b70bluetooth.wma) is how I sound with bluetooth. Is there a way I can configure a bluetooth headset to give the higher quality to the mic?

This has been a problem for various bt headsets I've used, but for the sake of providing all possible information: I'm using a Plantronics Voyager.

Audio file links borrowed from [this su question](https://superuser.com/questions/222541/quality-of-bluetooth-headsets-as-microphone).